# How to maintain multiple footer views in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ListView and often add/remove footers depending on list conditions.  Sometimes a progress view is displayed, other times an error view etc.  The point is that often I need to swap out the footer view.  But footer views must be added before setting or resetting the adapter so there are often weird exceptions in removing the existing footer view to replace it with a new one.  Yes, I have gotten null pointer exceptions, and adapter class cast exceptions just when removing the footer view!

So the bottom line: Its difficult and verbose and gross to maintain several footer views, but the footer real estate is useful.

So I was thinking about having just one footer which would just be a container, set this footer in the beginning and than add/remove/hide sub footer views to the footerview as needed.

Is this the best way to handle this?  Will the footerview properly refresh without resetting the adapter if I add in the sub footer views to the exiting footerview?

Is there a refresh option for the footer view without resetting adapter?  How are other folks handling this out there?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that ListView creates and discards items as they come into or go out of screen. So if you reference the items independently it is very likely that you'll get null pointer exceptions and many other errors. 
Your actual problem is precisely that and not the different types of footers.

So before dealing with a footer make sure that the item is actually visible (not null and inside the screen either fully or partially.)

Better yet post your code, maybe we will be able to target a specific (better) solution.

Comment: How would one determine if the footer referenced is visible?

Comment: Why does Android SDK not provide clear methods to add/remove footers that don't break?

Comment: In your adapter implementation keep a HashMap that maps from list item View to your item footer View. in the getView implementation make sure to update the map list item View reference to reference to the new footer View. Now each time you want to manipulate with any item footer View first check if it is mapped by any of the list item Views. Remember that the set of list item Views never change since the ListView takes care of recycling them, but their contents and consequently the footers will change - that's why you keep the hash map.

Comment: Android does provide a solid header footer manipulation API, it is up to you to utilise them in a way that's compatible with the workmanship of the API. Remember that each API has preconditions and postconditions. It is up to you to honour them in order to have consistent code.

Comment: Why don't you post your solution in terms of the getView() and the HashMap.  How would getView be the place to do the mapping?  Is it not only when you do addFooterView(v) that you know a view is a footerview?  This is not clear from your answer.

Comment: +1 at least you partial answered the question.  Thats more than most on this FORUM.

Comment: For overall ListView headers and footers see here :  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean) It clearly indicates that ListView header and footer must be specified before the list content/adapter is specified, such that the ListView was able to wrap your adapter in a proxy that also caters for the header and footer. If you wan to be able to hot swap headers and footers then you can hold N + 2 objects in your actual list - then update object[0] and object[N-1] then call notifyDatasetChanged().

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what I have in mind

1. Define an Array adapter

   ```
   public class CustomArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T>{

           // override all of the constructors as follows

           public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) {
                   super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
           }

           public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects) {
                   super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
           }

           public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) {
                   super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
           }

           public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects) {
                   super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
           }

           public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
                   super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
           }

           public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
                   super(context, textViewResourceId);
           }

           Map<View, View> footerMappings = new HashMap<View, View>();

           public View getView(int position, View recycleView, ViewGroup parent){
                   if(recycleView == null){
                           //Initialize the view here
                   } else {
                           //Clean up the view from old data
                   }

                   // Populate with current data

                   View footerView = create and assign the footer view here

                   this.footherMappings.put(recycleView, footerView); // this will overwrite the mappings that are out of the view
                   return recycleView;
           }

           public boolean isFooterVisible(View footerView){
                   Set<View> keys = this.footerMappings.keySet();
                   for(View key : keys){
                           if(this.footerMappings.get(key) == footerView){
                                   return true;
                           }
                   }
                   return false;
           }
   }
   ```
2. Use CustomArrayAdapter in your ListView

   ```
   ListView lv = new ListView(context);
   lv.setAdapter(new CustomeArrayAdapter(context, 0, your_object_list));
   ```
3. When you want to manipulate with a footer

   ```
   CustomeArrayAdapter adapter = (CustomeArrayAdapter)lv.getAdapter();
   if(adapter.isFooterVisible(your_footer_view)){
           // do whatever you want here
   } else {
           // footer is not in the view. Do something else
   }
   ```

Hope this will help...